# Why doesn't the post request in Postman update my mongo db collection?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm using Postman to practice updating my mongo database and collection. My two collections are users and products.
Here is my Product Schema :

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ProductSchema = new Schema({
title: {
type: String,
required: true,
},
description: {
type: String,
required: true,
},
price: {
type: Number,
required: true,
},
image: {
type: String,
},
location: {
type: String,
required: true,
},
condition: {
type: String,
required: true,
},
category: {
type: String,
required: true,
enum: \["Cars", "Electronics", "Clothing", "Furniture", "Other"\],
},
seller: {
type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
ref: "User",
},
createdAt: {
type: Date,
default: Date.now,
},
});

const Product = mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema);
export default Product;
```

Here is my User Schema :

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
firstName: {
type: String,
required: true,
min: 2,
max: 50,
},
lastName: {
type: String,
required: true,
min: 2,
max: 50,
},
email: {
type: String,
required: true,
unique: true,
},
password: {
type: String,
required: true,
},
location: {
type: String,
required: true,
},
products: [
{
type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
ref: "Product",
},
],
createdAt: {
type: Date,
default: Date.now,
},
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
export default User
```

My port is 3005.
Here are my routes that I use in my index.js file:

```
app.use("/product",productRoutes);
app.use("/user", userRoutes);
```

Here is the user route I use to try to add a product into my product collection as well as update the array of products I have as an existing user in my user collection.

```
router.post(":uid/add-product",  addProduct);
```

Here is the controller function addProduct :

```
export const addProduct = async (req, res, next) => {
try {
const id = req.params.uid;
const user = await User.findById(id);
if (!user) {
return res.status(404).json({ message: "User not found" });
}

      const product = new Product({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        price: req.body.price,
        image: req.body.image,
        location: req.body.location,
        condition: req.body.condition,
        category: req.body.category,
        seller: user._id,
      });
      
      await product.save();
      user.products.push(product._id);
      await user.save();
      
      res.status(200).json(user.products);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(404).json({ message: err.message });
    }

};
```

In Postman I send a POST request to this url :

```
"http://localhost:3005/user/63e93470d58236724ef10162/add-product"
```

with this raw JSON body data:

```
{
"title": "New Product",
"description": "great for anything",
"price": 2000,
"image": "pexels.com",
"location": "Dubai",
"condition": "new",
"category": "Clothing",
}
```

However, when I send the Post request, I get back a 404 error. I'm out of my wits on what to do to fix this. The get requests to receive information on my product and user collections work completely fine. I just don't understand why post requests don't work. Not even ChatGPT knows haha. Anyone who can help me with this will have all my gratitude. Thanks.

Comment: I would add server side logging to see whether the `addProduct` function is even called when accessing that route. anyway, if it is, i see you added error messages as the body of the 404. do you see those in the reply?

Comment: All routes should start with `/` so it should be `router.post("/:uid/add-product"`